# Enforce view's tag is unique in an application?

Tags: android, ios, tags, cocos2d-iphone, unique

in iOS or other platforms, tag is used to identify a class of view.

```
eg) myView.tag = TAG_MY_VIEW;
for(aView in self.view.subviews)
{
if aView.tag == TAG_MY_VIEW
do something;
}
```

When I start to use tags for many classes, it starts to get me worried about the possibility of tag number clash.

How do you enforce tag numbers are unique in your application?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, you can store more information about any object as well as avoid collision using aasociated objects:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(theObject, @"Some Other Object", "key");
```

to retrieve the info:

```
NSString *info = objc_getAssociatedObject(theObject, "key");
```

Works with an NSDictionary or custom classes/any class as well.